# rsync latest n files from remote server

Tags: find, rsync, ls

Long time reader, first time poster.

I'm trying to rsync the latest few log files from a remote server to my laptop. I've gotten close with this:

`ssh -qx root@example.org "cd /path/to/logs && find . -mtime -1 -print0" | rsync --from0 --files-from=- -avHS "root@example.org:/path/to/logs/" .`

But that syncs all the files from the past day, which is too many. Ideally I'd like to just download the last half dozen or so files. I know this will list the latest 6 files:

`ls -t|head -6`

But I'm not sure how to use these two bits of info together (if it's even possible) to solve my problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try `ssh -qx root@example.org " ls -t  /path/to/logs | head -6 " | rsync....` ?

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I played with it and this worked:

`ssh -qx root@example.org "ls -t /path/to/logs | head -6" | rsync --files-from=- -avHS root@example.org:/path/to/logs/ .`

Comment: I've converted my comment to answer, please accept if it works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
ssh -qx root@example.org "ls -t /path/to/logs | head -6" | rsync --files-from=- -avHS root@example.org:/path/to/logs/ .
```

Comment: Thanks! The exact syntax that worked for me was:

`ssh -qx root@example.org "ls -t /path/to/logs | head -6" | rsync --files-from=- -avHS root@example.org:/path/to/logs/ .`